# ERROR: Error installing psych: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: windows, yaml, psych

I am trying to update psych to 5.0.0, but I get the following error message:

```
Updating psych
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing psych:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/psych-5.0.0/ext/psych
C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0 extconf.rb
checking for yaml.h... no
yaml.h not found
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
.
.
.

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.1.0/psych-5.0.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/psych-5.0.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.1.0/psych-5.0.0/gem_make.out
```

Tried `gem update`, `gem pristine --all`, same error.

Any tips how to fix this in Windows?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how it was fixed but I ran `gem update` and psych was updated to 5.0.2 without an error.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem on Mac running OSX 13.2. Bundle install failed because it couldn't find yaml.h.

Since I was on Mac and running Homebrew, I did a

```
brew install libyaml
```

and then re-ran bundle install. It worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

"pacman: The term 'pacman' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again"

You should use the MSYS2 terminal like "pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libyaml". It will install into MSYS2 which will be accessible to windows

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to comment because it may be that other people face the same problem and this could help. I solved this problem on Windows 11 pro by running powershell as administrator and then running the "gem update" command. The system updated psych and I was able to create projects using the "rails new" command. Before the terminal showed an error message that said "Installing psych 5.1.2 with native extensions
error: failed to start transaction (unable to lock database)
error: unable to lock database: Permission denied
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension."

Answer (score -1):

You need to install libyaml via `pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libyaml`in the command prompt with ruby

Comment: He is asking for a solution on Windows, not on ArchLinux. Also, this package doesn’t exist.

Comment: @AndréKugland Any idea how to do that in Windows? Thank you

Comment: @Ioannis, I’m sorry, I didn’t know that MSYS2 used a port of ArchLinux’s pacman. BartK’s answer might be correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, it it not:

`pacman: The term 'pacman' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`